# join para campo pesquisa

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Fiz pergunta com outro usuário mas não sei o que aconteceu que não consegui recuperar as informações e tive que criar outro agora. Enfim, queria criar um campo pesquisa e me deram como resposta a controller e view abaixo:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ModelDb db;
    public HomeController()
    {
       db = new ModelDb();
    }

   ~HomeController()
    {
      db.Dispose();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Pesquisa()
    {
       return View();
    } 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Pesquisa(string texto)
    {
        return View(db.Pessoas.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(texto)).OrderBy(x => x.Nome));
    }
}
```

View

```cs
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Pessoas>
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Pesquisa</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
         <p>Digite o nome</p>
         <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" placeholder="Digite a pesquisa" />
         <div><button type="submit">Filtrar</button></div>   
     }
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
    </tr>
@{
        if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.PessoaId</td>
                    <td>@item.Nome</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Ótimo, era exatamente isso que eu precisava Harry Polter! Só que agora, preciso fazer a mesma coisa mas na view tenho que retornar informação de duas tabelas diferentes. Qual a sintaxe para fazer um join no controller ou como faço para chamar isso na view já que não posso colocar dois models como:

```cs
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Pessoas>
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Informacoes>
```

?

**Os models**

```cs
namespace Competências.Models
{
public class Informacoes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Chapa é obrigatória.")]
    [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "A Chapa pode ter no máximo 16 caracteres.")]
    public string Chapa { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Nome é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(120, ErrorMessage = "O Nome pode ter no máximo 120 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class Pessoas
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigatório descrever as atividades desempenhadas na empresa")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "O campo atividades pode ter no máximo 255 caracteres")]
    public string Atividades { get; set; }


    public int InformacoesId { get; set; }
    public virtual Informacoes Informacoes { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Passe seu modelo na pergunta por favor e foi eu que respondi a anterior

Comment: Não dá para passar dois model na mesma view, deve se usar ViewBag ou ViewData !!!

Comment: Isso! Foi vc mesmo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Era isso mesmo que precisava! Só que preciso na hora do retorno juntamente com o campo texto, retornar a informação Chapa e Nome de outra tabela no grid! Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1):

Para passar informações do *Controller* para *View* use [ViewBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) ou [ViewData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

***Exemplo:***

Perceba que *ViewBag.Fluxo* será o transporte para a sua View, pode ser usada normalmente para diversos tipos de dados.

```cs
public ActionResult Pesquisa(string texto)
{
        ViewBag.Fluxo = db.Fluxo.AsEnumerable();
        return View(db.Pessoas.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(texto)).OrderBy(x => x.Nome));
}
```

***View:***

```cs
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Pessoas>
@{ Layout = null; }
@{    
    IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Fluxo> modelFluxo = (IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Fluxo>)ViewBag.Fluxo;
}
```

---

***Outra maneira seria com uma classe Modelo***

***Exemplo:***

```cs
public class Models
{
    public IList Model { get; set; }
    public Models()
    {
        Model = new List<Object>();
    }
    public void Add(Object model)
    {
        this.Model.Add(model);
    }
}
```

***Controller***

```cs
public ActionResult Pesquisa(string texto)
{
    Models.Models model = new Models.Models();
    model.Add(db.Fluxo);
    model.Add(db.Pessoas.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(texto)).OrderBy(x => x.Nome));
    return View(model);
}
```

***View:***

```cs
@model WebApp.Models.Models
@{ Layout = null; }
@{  
    IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Fluxo> modelFluxo = null;
    IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Pessoas> modelPessoa = null;
    if (Model != null) { 
        modelFluxo = Model.Model[0] as IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Fluxo>;
        modelPessoa = Model.Model[1] as IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Pessoas>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show de bola! Só precisei adicionar um "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" na minha connection string e funcionou beleza! Me ajudou demais!!!